# Не выводится изображение из файла ресурсов

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qlabel, qrc

Не получается вывести изображение в `label` из файла ресурсов.  
Сам файл отрабатывает без ошибок, но изображение не выводится.

Не знаю, в чём может быть причина?

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1122, 914)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-10, -30, 1141, 901))
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/image/kit.png"))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 80, 561, 111))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(28)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.listView = QtWidgets.QListView(self.centralwidget)
        self.listView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 430, 1041, 421))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI Black")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.listView.setFont(font)
        self.listView.setObjectName("listView")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 360, 291, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Yu Gothic")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1122, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Программа"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Обновить данные"))
import imagepy_rc


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**imagepy.qrc**

```
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="image">
    <file>kit.png</file>
    <file>background.png</file>
    <file>new.jpg</file>
  </qresource>
  <qresource/>
</RCC>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **imagepy.qrc**

---

```
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="/">
    <file>image/kit.png</file>
    <file>image/background.png</file>
    <file>image/new.jpg</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

---

2. `pyrcc5 imagepy.qrc -o imagepy_rc.py`

---

3. `python main.py`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: No resources in resource description. Вот такую ошибку выводит на втором этапе

Comment: Все разобрался. Спасибо за помощь.